# Grouping rows based on two columns and create a third column, find groups with less than x and combine with other groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a large dataframe (100.000 rows) with many columns. These are the relevant columns for my question:

```
id   herd        birth     H_BY  HYcount      death       H_DY   HYcount2
1    1345   2005-01-09    134505       1  2010-01-09    134510       1
2    1345   2010-03-05    134510       2  2015-01-09    134515       2
3    1345   2010-05-10    134510       2  2015-01-09    134515       2
4    1345   2011-06-01    134511       1  2016-01-09    134516       1
5    1345   2012-09-01    134512       1  2017-01-09    134517       2
6    1345   2015-09-13    134515       1  2017-01-09    134517       2
7    1346   2015-10-01    134615       3  2019-01-09    134619       1
8    1346   2015-10-27    134615       3  2020-01-09    134620       2
9    1346   2015-11-10    134615       3  2020-01-09    134620       2
10   1346   2016-12-10    134616       1  2021-01-09    134621       1
```

I am creating Herd-year fixed effects.
I have already combined the herd and birth/death columns into herd+birth year and herd+death year into separate columns and counted how many time each fixed effect appears in the dataframe. As can be seen above.

However, now I want to check my whole dataframe for HYcount and HYcount2 that are less then 3. So I don't want any that are either 1 or 2 in a HY group.

I would like to run though the dataframe and combine those HY groups that are 1 or 2 per group into other groups. Below or above.

**EDIT**

*I also want to only combine HY groups WITHIN EACH HERD!*

*So I don't want to add a herd member of one herd to another herd with the Herd-year variable.*

Here is what I've tried with the birth year fixed effect.

```
#Sort the df by the relevant value
df= df.sort_values(by=['H_BY'])


df.loc[
    (df['HYcount'] < 3),
    'H_BY'] = df['H_BY'].shift(-1)

#Count the values again 
df['HC1_c'] = df.groupby('H_BY')['H_BY'].transform('count')
```

But this is a very feeble attempt. I have to run through this many many times to rid my dataframe of all values that are less then 3 and it does not work with record number 1. And I want to repeat this process over at least 4 other columns.

**EDIT**

And of course this code does not do anything about combining *within* one herd.

Any tips and trick or ideas how I can do this more efficiently?

**EDIT**

Excepted outcome with the data above.

```
id   herd        birth     H_BY  HYcount      death       H_DY   HYcount2
1    1345   2005-01-09    134510       3  2010-01-09    134515       3
2    1345   2010-03-05    134510       3  2015-01-09    134515       3
3    1345   2010-05-10    134510       3  2015-01-09    134515       3
4    1345   2011-06-01    134515       3  2016-01-09    134517       3
5    1345   2012-09-01    134515       3  2017-01-09    134517       3
6    1345   2015-09-13    134515       3  2017-01-09    134517       3

7    1346   2015-10-01    134615       4  2019-01-09    134620       4
8    1346   2015-10-27    134615       4  2020-01-09    134620       4
9    1346   2015-11-10    134615       4  2020-01-09    134620       4
10   1346   2016-12-10    134615       4  2021-01-09    134620       4
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "However, now I want to check my whole dataframe for HYcount and HYcount2 that are less then 3. So I don't want any that are either 1 or 2 in a HY group." If you are looking only for less than 3 and now wanting 1 or 2s in it. Do you mean you want to drop the rows that have less than 3 counts?

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear enough. I don't want to drop any rows. If the HY_count is only 1 or 2, I want to edit the herd or the birth year or the H_BY column and change it to the H_BY that is above or below the row. And when I count again how many animals are in each H_BY I want only groups with 3+. But in the full dataframe I have over 1000 herds and I don't want to combine IDs from one herd to another herd with this method.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected output?

Comment: Yes, I have done that now. Maybe this is an impossible task :)

Comment: I think this task is not so hard but I'm really having a hard time understanding the task. You don't really explain how H_BYs are being grouped or why the expected output appears as it is. What you're trying to do is quite obscure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up this problem I removed the `H_BY` and `H_DY` columns in order to allow dynamic counting of the groups. One of the problems with having the counts in the DataFrame is that, as mentioned, you need to recalculate it any
time you change the groupings, as well as it is easy to double count.

I then change `birth` and `death` to `datetimes` in order to create the new columns for birth year and death year, `by` and `dy`.

```py
ff = df[[ 'herd', 'birth', 'death' ]].copy()

ff[ 'birth' ] = pd.to_datetime( ff[ 'birth' ] )
ff[ 'death' ] = pd.to_datetime( ff[ 'death' ] )
ff = ff.assign( 
    by = lambda x: x.birth.apply( lambda y: y.year ),
    dy = lambda x: x.death.apply( lambda y: y.year )
)
```

|  | herd | birth | death | by | dy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1345 | 2005-01-09 | 2010-01-09 | 2005 | 2010 |
| 1 | 1345 | 2010-03-05 | 2015-01-09 | 2010 | 2015 |
| 2 | 1345 | 2010-05-10 | 2015-01-09 | 2010 | 2015 |
| 3 | 1345 | 2011-06-01 | 2016-01-09 | 2011 | 2016 |
| 4 | 1345 | 2012-09-01 | 2017-01-09 | 2012 | 2017 |
| 5 | 1345 | 2015-09-13 | 2017-01-09 | 2015 | 2017 |
| 6 | 1346 | 2015-10-01 | 2019-01-09 | 2015 | 2019 |
| 7 | 1346 | 2015-10-27 | 2020-01-09 | 2015 | 2020 |
| 8 | 1346 | 2015-11-10 | 2020-01-09 | 2015 | 2020 |
| 9 | 1346 | 2016-12-10 | 2021-01-09 | 2016 | 2021 |

For the actual processing we begin by grouping by `herd` so we don't mix between them. We then merge groups forward if possible, otherwise backwards, until no more merges must occur. Finally we assign the groups back to the original data.

```py
tdf = []
for herd, data in ff.groupby( 'herd' ):
    # get counts and assign initial groups
    counts = data[ 'by' ].value_counts().sort_index().to_frame()
    counts[ 'group' ] = range( counts.shape[ 0 ] )
    
    while True:
        gcounts = counts.groupby( 'group' ).sum()[ 'by' ]  # group counts
        change = gcounts[ gcounts.values < 3 ]  # groups with too few
        
        if change.shape[ 0 ] == 0:
            # no changes, exit
            break

        # check how to merge groups
        cgroup = change.index.min()
        groups = gcounts.index.values
        g_ind = list( groups ).index( cgroup )
        if ( g_ind + 1 ) < groups.shape[ 0 ]:
            # merge forward
            ngroup = groups[ g_ind + 1 ]
            
        elif g_ind > 0:
            # merge backward
            ngroup = groups[ g_ind - 1 ]
            
        else:
            # no groups to merge
            print( f'Can not merge herd {herd}' )
            break

        counts.loc[ counts[ 'group' ] == cgroup, 'group' ] = ngroup 

    # assign groups
    for ind, gdata in counts.iterrows():
        data.loc[ data[ 'by' ] == ind, 'group' ] = gdata[ 'group' ]
        
    tdf.append( data )
    
tdf = pd.concat( tdf )
```

|  | herd | birth | death | by | dy | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1345 | 2005-01-09 | 2010-01-09 | 2005 | 2010 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 1345 | 2010-03-05 | 2015-01-09 | 2010 | 2015 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 1345 | 2010-05-10 | 2015-01-09 | 2010 | 2015 | 1.0 |
| 3 | 1345 | 2011-06-01 | 2016-01-09 | 2011 | 2016 | 4.0 |
| 4 | 1345 | 2012-09-01 | 2017-01-09 | 2012 | 2017 | 4.0 |
| 5 | 1345 | 2015-09-13 | 2017-01-09 | 2015 | 2017 | 4.0 |
| 6 | 1346 | 2015-10-01 | 2019-01-09 | 2015 | 2019 | 0.0 |
| 7 | 1346 | 2015-10-27 | 2020-01-09 | 2015 | 2020 | 0.0 |
| 8 | 1346 | 2015-11-10 | 2020-01-09 | 2015 | 2020 | 0.0 |
| 9 | 1346 | 2016-12-10 | 2021-01-09 | 2016 | 2021 | 0.0 |

Finally, if you still want the `H_BY` identifier for grouping you can use

```py
tdf[ 'H_BY' ] = tdf[ 'herd' ].astype( 'str' ) + tdf[ 'group' ].astype( int ).astype( str )
```

Comment: This is fantastic and works! Thank you for taking the time to help me. Can I ask: Can I make this into a function if I want to do this kind of grouping in regards of other columns, let's say I have four other datetime columns that I also want to create Herd-year groups with.

Comment: Ye.ah, you can easily turn it into a function by wrapping the given code in a function and replacing any of the hard coded column names with those passed in as parameters. If you do go that route, I also suggest creating names for the grouping columns based off of the passed in column names. e.g. `def group( df, group_col ):`